# How to deploy docker containers on to gcloud compute instance using travis ci?

Tags: docker, cloud, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to deploy docker containers from my local machine, test them on Travis CI, Build them and push them to the Container Repository, and then deploy them on my gcloud compute instance. But I can't figure out how to do it and was wondering if someone had done this before and if they could point me to some material that would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with Docker:  [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) you can find how to use Docker with Travis CI. At first, you need to install [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and Google [recommend](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) to use version 18.03 or newer because it's required to use gcloud credential helper for authentication. Also, you need to install [Google SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) and [enable](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project) billing for your project. [Check](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) that you have permission to push and pull images to Google Container Registry and don't forget to enable `Container Registry API` in your project. After that, you can build Docker image, tag it with a registry name, push the image to Container Registry and than you'll be able to pull your images into your project. More information with examples and step by step instructions you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/).